# connection denied when trying to connect to ev3dev

Tags: localhost, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have problems connecting between ev3dev and the html program. I know I have the right ip address.
[ev3dev code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53mz3.png)[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh3nX.png)
[the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSPi.png)
I am quite inexperienced with such programs that talk together over the internet, thanks for all the help

I tried to get the html program and the program on ev3dev to communicate together.